# HttpUrlConnection request not working without reading the response

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to post a `json` request via `HttpUrlConnection` (Note that I just need to push data to the server, response will be ignored). I've run through few examples but still couldn't get it work, no data was added to the server.

Here's my code:

```
   URL url = new URL(urlString);
   connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   connection.setDoOutput(true);
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
   connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

   OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
   stream.write(requestJSON.toString().getBytes());
   stream.flush();
   stream.close();
```

**Update**

I noticed that the code works when I try to read the response after `stream.close()`, eg:

```
connection.getResponseMessage()
```

Is that means it's necessary to read the response in order to complete the request?

Comment: before of `stream.close()` add `connection.connect();`

Comment: Use like the following sample `OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
                writer.write(requestBody);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();`

Answer (score 1):

use this

if request is GET

```
 public static String getDataUsingGetRequest(String urlVal) {
    String Content = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlVal);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        Content = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    return Content;
}
```

// if request is post

```
public static String getDataUsingPostRequest(String urlStr,  String inputJson) {

    String result = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.connect();
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(inputJson);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```